# Use Python lists in Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

I couldn't find this question, although I am sure it has been asked.

How could I use a python list to condense this script?  This code block currently works, but is clearly not very efficient.

```
def Reclass(test):
if test == '2 7':
    return 'Padmounted Single Phase'
elif test == '2 4':
    return 'Padmounted Three Phase'
elif test == '2 2':
    return 'Padmounted Three Phase'
elif test == '2 1':
    return 'Padmounted Three Phase'
elif test == '1 4':
    return 'OH Single Phase'
elif test == '1 2':
    return 'OH Single Phase'
elif test == '1 1':
    return 'OH Single Phase'
elif test == '1 5':
    return 'OH Second Phase'
elif test == '1 3':
    return 'OH Second Phase'
elif test == '1 7':
    return 'OH Third Phase'
```

I was attempting to use (as an example of a list):

```
elif test == ['1 1', '1 2', '1 3']
```

but the code was being skipped over and not working.

Comment: Technically I think this is a pure Python rather than GIS Question and would be better researched/asked at [**StackOverflow**](http://stackoverflow.com) with references to the Field Calculator removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`elif test in ['1 1', '1 2', '1 3']`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary.  Something like this:

```
test_dict = {'2 7':'Padmounted Single Phase', '2 4':'Padmounted Three Phase', ....}
```

then you can get the answer

```
def reclass(test):
   return test_dict[test]
```